# Safari css rotate 3d layering issue

Tags: css, safari, transform

I am creating a disk using CSS3's transform rotateX that should have text on top of it. However I am running into an issue in Safari that the text cuts through the disk. You can an example codepen of it here : http://codepen.io/nichmekof/pen/ZYbRgx

It works the way I want in all other browsers, it's just Safari that's causing the issues.

```
transform: rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

Anyone have any ideas on fixing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess safari uses the `-webkit` prefix

> [RESOURCE](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Using2Dand3DTransforms/Using2Dand3DTransforms.html)

also your problem can be solved by also adding a small rotation to your text

```
&:nth-child(1) { -webkit-transform: rotateX(5deg) translate(20px, 280px); }
```

Comment: It's not the -webkit prefix as I have autoprefixer on. The rotating works for the side bits of text but doesn't help the bottom bit of text.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the answer to my own question.

Just need to use translate3d instead of just translate.

```
&:nth-child(1) { transform: translate3d(20px, 280px, 300px); }
```